# Recursive xslt template not replacing all characters found

Tags: .net, xml, xslt-1.0

I've created this XSLT template below to parse through a block of text being converted for an HTML page. This template is used in multiple locations, however, it is not successfully converting the characters I have specified all the time. An example would be as follows:

I want “two” have “help” and I continue to look  “four” more, but all I find is  “emptiness”.

The result is:
I want "two" have "helpâ€ and I continue to look "forâ€ more, but all I find is "emptiness".

Any thoughts?

```
<xsl:template name="PreserveQuotations">
  <xsl:param name="text"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text,'&#8220;')">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'&#8220;')"/>
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="PreserveQuotations">
        <xsl:with-param name="text">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'&#8220;')"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text,'&#8221;')">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'&#8221;')"/>
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="PreserveQuotations">
        <xsl:with-param name="text">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'&#8221;')"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem should become clear to you if you think about the case of a string of the form

```
aaa &#8221; bbb &#8220; ccc
```

There are two obvious solutions:  (1) check for the case where the string contains both special characters and then handle the first one that occurs; or (2) do one pass over the string for each character.  (Either split the template into two templates or specify which character to look for in a parameter.)